# I have a problem with the strummer in Ample Guitar M (used in Reaper)

Tags: guitar, daw, strumming, vst, cockos-reaper

When I create a riff using the plugin and drag it in the timeline (as a midi file), it's played with no legatos or really anything I set up in the riffer. It sound terrible, all the chords are played in a sort of staccato and the guitar doesn't sound like it's strumming at all. Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What are the velocities for the imported MIDI? If they're too low, then they might sound staccato. Is quantization turned on in Reaper?